Attempting to click form button for element to be visible, enable and stable
I am trying to click on submit button using Playwright, but can't make it work. I have following html code.
<table>
    <tr>
      <td id="ct100" onscroll="scollPosition(this);">
        <!-- some html form -->
         <input value="Save" type="submit" class="btn" />
      </td>
      <td id="ct101" onscroll="scollPosition(this);">
         <input type="text" id="input_01" onchange="updateValue();" />
         <!-- form input -->
      </td>
</table>

Playwright code:
   async saveSetupPage(): Promise<void> {
      // If I try to click submit button before any filling up any input, click is working 

      await page.locator("#input_01").click();
      await page.locator("#input_01").fill("some value");
      // trying to fill 10-12 input with same above code

      // now trying to click on submit button
      await page.locator("//*[@id='ct100_btn']").click();
   }); 
      

Now I've got the following error:
 locator.click: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.

 Call log:
   - waiting for locator('//*[@id="ct100_btn"]')
   -   locator resolved to <input value="Save" type="submit" class="btn" id="../>
   - attempting click action
   -   waiting for element to be visible, enable and stable
   -   scrolling into view if needed
   -   done scrolling
   -   <div class="UpdateProgress">


Avoid XPath. ct100_btn isn't in your HTML. Try "#ct100 .btn". But if fixing that doesn't work, please share more information about the page to reproduce the issue. There may be an overlay, an iframe, a cloudflare block, arbitrary JS behavior or timing, or some additional context that needs to be provided to explain the failure. See [mcve] for help.

Thank you very much for your help, my problem is not solved yet. Based on your suggestion, It seems problem is not in save button. There are lot of js code, which could be the issue.

I had a similar issue before. My problem was, that when I filled up the input, some client validator was failing, hence submit button was disabled.
Try to check if any server/client side validation failed or not and submit button is disabled or not.
Hope it will be helpful.

as @ggorlen
has said, your locator seems to be incorrect ("//*[@id='ct100_btn']"), as there is no such element in your HTML snippet.
Instead, use a more accurate locator based on the available attributes, such as class or value. and also make sure that the Playwright waits for the elements to be visible, enabled, and stable before interacting with them such as something like this for your Playwrite code
async saveSetupPage(): Promise<void> {
  await page.locator("#input_01").fill("some value");
  await page.waitForTimeout(1000); 
  await page.locator("input[type='submit'][value='Save']").click();
  await page.waitForNavigation(); 

}

waitForTimeout() is not recommended. You should use it only for debugging. .click() has an auto-wait therefore waitForTimeout() is unnecessary. waitForNavigation() is deprecated and replaced by waitForUrl() but I don´t  see for what purpose you propose that.

Thank you for your feedback! I understand that using  waitForTimeout() is generally not recommended but I felt the application’s form elements and their interactions, such as onscroll and onchange, can cause additional dynamic content loading or updates and using waitForTimeout() ensures that all these dynamic changes have completed before proceeding with the next actions as it  provides a buffer period to handle any unexpected delays in rendering or JavaScript execution.
Thanks again for the helpful advice and I will read more about it and try it moving forward

Thank you very much for your help, my problem is not solved yet. I'm trying to figure it out.

@GifftyCode waitForTImeout shouldn't be used for that. Use waitForFunction, waitForResponse or waitForSelector to wait for the specific changes. Anyway, OP never shared a page so how do you know there are dynamic loads? waitForNavigation is deprecated and in the wrong place, so this causes a race condition that can hang the script. It needs to be set before the action that triggers nav, not after.

@sabbir Consider sharing a [mcve] as requested, so people don't have to guess your use case. What exactly isn't solved yet?

Here’s how you can resolve the issue with clicking the submit button using Playwright in your given scenario:
Problem
The locator.click action times out because Playwright is unable to find the submit button with the specified selector (//*[@id='ct100_btn']). The provided HTML does not have an element with the ID ct100_btn.
Solution
Update the selector to correctly target the submit button based on your provided HTML.
HTML
<table>
    <tr>
      <td id="ct100" onscroll="scollPosition(this);">
        <!-- some html form -->
         <input value="Save" type="submit" class="btn" />
      </td>
      <td id="ct101" onscroll="scollPosition(this);">
         <input type="text" id="input_01" onchange="updateValue();" />
         <!-- form input -->
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>

Playwright Code
async saveSetupPage(): Promise<void> {
// Fill the input field
await page.locator("#input_01").fill("some value");

// Click the submit button
await page.locator('td#ct100 input[type="submit"]').click();
}

